# Have a multi-line description

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I don't manage to find how to make a multi-line description in my firefox add-on.
What I want to achieve, is that when somebody click on the 'More' of my add-on (in the add-on manager), he will see something like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
Ut enim ad minim veniam.

Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
```

The documentation is no help ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#description)) as they only talk about short description.
I found a not to complicated add-on with multi-line description, but couldn't find how he manage to do it by looking at the code (It even show a picture) : [Simple storage](https://github.com/ghostery/addon-simple-storage-editor).

So how to have multi-line description (with image and link) showing in the add-ons manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description you refer to is provided by the author manually, not through the `install.rdf`,by editing the addon's info at AMO (specifically the Add-on Details section).